# Never display SoftKeyboard on Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write an Android app, which shouldn't let users use SoftKeyboard. Because, I want users to scan barcodes to input into editText. I don't want SoftKeyboard to show up.

I read many articles and pages on Stack-overflow, and all suggest me to use the below line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

But, the above line doesn't block users to the SoftKeyboard, users can still use the SoftKeyboard.

What is the best way to block users to use SoftKeyboard once and for all?

Regards

Comment: If you don't want users to be able to edit the text then what is the point of using editText in the first place?

Comment: @UnBanned, I want users to input values by scanning barcodes.

Comment: I understood that, but I don't get why you wouldn't use a TextView and just do textView.SetText(barcodeStr) 

Answer (score 1):

This might help if you want to block focus on your editText.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:cursorVisible="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. the keyboard still pops up

Comment: could you paste your whole layout?